# TypeScript - wait for an observable/promise to finish, and return observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I am quite new to TypeScript & RxJS, and I am trying to return an `Observable` after another `Observable` is finished:

```
public myObservable = () : Observable<boolean> => {
    console.log('retrieving the token in DB');
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            observer.next(true);
            observer.complete();
        }, 5000);
    });
}

public makeRequest = (): Observable<any> => {
    return this.myObservable().subscribe(
        function (x) {
            console.log('I have the token, now I can make the HTTP call');

            return this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
                .map( (responseData) => {
                    return responseData.json();
                })
                .map((item:any) => {
                    return {
                        id: item.id,
                        userId: item.userId,
                        title: item.title,
                        body: item.body
                    };
                });

        },
        function (err) {
            console.error('Error: ' + err);
        },
        function () {
            console.log('Completed');
        });

}
```

I received this error: "Returned expression type subscription is not assignable to type `Observable<any>`".

I totally understand the error here *(an Observable is like a stream, and a subscription is the fact of "observing" that stream)*, but I don't see how to "wait" for an `Observable` *(or a promise)* to finish to return a new `Observable`. How can I do that?

Comment: great hint! My 2 cents: flatMap() doesn't seem to be available in rxjs 5.0.1. I used mergeMap() to achieve a "chain" of observables or in other words - have an outer and 2 inner observables.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that we convert observable into different type... with `.subscribe` - while we should not (it does not return observable)

```
public makeRequest = (): Observable<any> => {
    return this.myObservable().subscribe(
      ... // this is wrong, we cannot return .subscribe
          // because it consumes observable and returns ISusbcriber
    );
}
```

When we have an observable... we should just take its result and use .map to convert it to something else

> #### [`FlatMap` operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)
>
> transform the items emitted by an Observable into Observables, then
>   flatten the emissions from those into a single Observable

```
public makeRequest = (): Observable<any> => {
    return this.myObservable()
       .flatmap((x) => return this.http
              .get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
              .map( (responseData) => {
                    return responseData.json();
              })
              ...
```

Check all the details here

#### [TAKING ADVANTAGE OF OBSERVABLES IN ANGULAR 2](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html)

Comment: flatmap/mergemap example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mergemap

Answer (score 18):

While flatMap() may work, since you are not passing in a parameter that is used[see param (x)], the best operator for you to use in this scenario is forkJoin().

Please see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38049268/1742393

```
   Observable.forkJoin(
    this.http.get('/app/books.json').map((res:Response) => res.json()),
    this.http.get('/app/movies.json').map((res:Response) => res.json())
).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.books = data[0]
    this.movies = data[1]
  },
  err => console.error(err)
);
```

Comment: Is the returned data order always as shown?  this.book = data[0] and this.movies = data[1]

Comment: Yes, it directly correlates to the order of observables you passed into the method.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for this answer some days because this is my problem too. Today I have the answer and would like to share.

The code is:

```
ngOnInit() {
var idEntidade: number;

this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  idEntidade = Number(params.get('id'));
});

this.dataService.getEstados().subscribe(data => {
  this.estados = data;
});

var dados = this.dataService.getCliente(idEntidade);

**this.subscription = dados.subscribe(
  (data: Cliente) => { this.entityForm.patchValue(data);},
  null,
  () => { this.completed(); }
  );**
}
```

and the function completed will be executed after the subscribe is complete.

```
completed(){
let idEstado: number = this.entityForm.controls['estadoId'].value;

if (idEstado === null) {
  return;
}

this.dataService.getMunicipiosByEstado(this.entityForm.controls['estadoId'].value)
    .subscribe(data => { this.municipios = data; });
}
```

Hope this helps.