# JS Variable Doesn't Change in Timeout - Closure Issue?

Tags: javascript, typescript, closures

So I admit, every time I learn closures, I never use them and forget. Below I set a `didGeoLocExecute` boolean variable to false. Then I create a timeout. Once the timeout completes, I check if `didGeoLocExecute` was set later in the function.

It *is* being set, but in the timeout, it stays as the initial value. Is this a closure issue, if so, how do I handle it?

```
private getGeoLocation(): Observable<any> {
  let locObs = new Observable ( observer => {

  let didGeoLocExecute: boolean = false;

  setTimeout(() => {
    if(!didGeoLocExecute){
      console.log('TIME OUT! ' + didGeoLocExecute);
      observer.error();
    }
  }, 15000);

  let position: GeoCoordinates;

  this.location.getCurrentPosition().subscribe(
    location => {
      didGeoLocExecute = true;
      observer.next(); 
    },
    error => {
      didGeoLocExecute = true;
      observer.error();
    }
  );

});
```

P.S. I am pretty sure typescript and observables can safely be ignored for the sake of this question.

Comment: This is TypeScript, correct?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Yes, but it compiles down to JS, I think the issue is with the timeout, or the Observables creating new scope. Edit: The timeout is pure JS, which is why I am leaving off the typescript tag.

Comment: is `getCurrentPosition` asynchronous?

Comment: P.S. I already solved the "business logic" issue by moving out the variable into an Angular service (singleton for whoever doesn't use angular). Now I am just interested in this conceptually.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Yes, Observables work in the same way as promises (almost). location is the 'success' and 'error' is the error callback equivalent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304160/typescript-wait-for-an-observable-promise-to-finish-and-return-observable I found this question, I don't know enough about TS and observables to be much more help. This may be it

Comment: Thanks for the help, don't worry about this. I am going to type this up in raw javascript later and see if the issue still occurs. This is just intellectual curiosity at this point.